# Breaking agent forwarding in Ansible on Vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

Using Ansible to provision Vagrant box, Ansible fails when cloning Git repo: `Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`. Oddly I can clone from Git with no issues when I SSH into the box and run `git clone <GIT_URL>`. Have set `sudo: no` in Ansible task but still fails. `ssh-agent` is running correctly on both host and box.

Comment: Did you try using a provision shell `ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and in Vagrantfile `config.ssh.forward_agent = true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Host key verification failed.
```

is not related to the agent forwarding. As noted in the comments, it is related to the `known_hosts` file.

Before the first connection to the server (`github.com`), you need to manually verify it's host key, or use similar process as noted in comments, using keyscan:

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The other (not recommended) possibility is to turn off the host key verification in the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host git
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

in the home directory of the user running the `git clone`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we're using an internal git server thats DNS'd to `git` and when I run the keyscan command on it it doesn't come back with anything

Comment: I added the alternative option.